# Finding minima of $x^2$ function with derivatives

Tags: derivatives

Of course it is $0$.

with $-8$ ... $f(x^2): 64$

The derivative would be $f(2x): -16$

The derivative tells me about change and slope. From $x=-8$ and calculating derivatives I know I need to go down because of the negative sign. But I really don't understand what to do next? What does $-16$ tell me at all? To move $-16$ on $x$ axis? This way I get to: $-8-16 = -24$

$f(x^2): 576$. So it is obvious that this is wrong.

If I go $-16$ on $y$ axis I get $48$. This would make sense, but this means root of $48$ is my $x$.

But guys, how should I calculate the root of $48$ with no calculator? And function is so simple...

So I know I am missing something, I would appreciate if you could help me. Thank you.

Comment: What do you exactly need to do? Find the minimum value of $x^2$ using derivatives?

Comment: If you want to find minima of the function why did you choose the method you are explaining to us? Just do the classic thing.

Comment: @DylanZammit I am just trying to understand it. Yes, to find a minumum, but I would like to go step by step... And I am already stucked with -16 :)

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar I would like to understand this method. So if I am correct, I need to do 64-16 ? Is this the thing to do it?

Comment: This is extremely unclear and difficult to read; please post the *actual* problem you're working on, copied verbatim from its source. If you're just trying to compute $\sqrt{48}$, then notice $48 = 16 \cdot 3$, so $\sqrt{48} = 4 \sqrt{3}$; what this has to do with the rest of your question, I have no idea.

Comment: If you want to solve it **numerically** then you can say: $f(x+\Delta x)=f(x)+\Delta x \cdot f'(x)$, can you take this from here?

Comment: @user296602 Thanks for that. Sorry, I hardly passed math in high school :) Anyway, I am just trying to understand what -16 tells me.This is all.

Comment: The thing you are looking is somewhat like solving numerically. It can tell you that for instance: $f(-8+0.1)=f(-8)+0.1*f'(-8)$

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar I am just trying to understand what -16 tells me... I need to go down on y axis for -16 when x=-8... Is this it?

Comment: It is the slope of the line which tells you the next point. The next point as very near to the first one.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar Thanks. Just one more question... How do I get to this new point?

Comment: @Testingman $-16$ is *just* the slope of the graph of $y = x^2$ at the point $x = -8, y = 64$; that's literally all it tells you. I have no idea how this is connected with the question of "find the minima," at least partially because you haven't actually written down a clear version of the problem. A lot of the lack of clarity isn't the math - it's the vague writing that's riddled with so many typos....

Comment: @user296602 My goal is to find the minima, step by step by step. But I have a problem with understanding what -16 tells me to do. So if slope of f(x^2) = -16... what is the next X if first was -8?

Comment: If you're trying to find the minima, **why** are you involving $x = -8$ at all? For the third time... please copy-paste the **exact** problem that you are working on, verbatim from the source. Until the question is clarified, I'm voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @user296602 This is my problem, my source, there is no link or anything... I decided I will find minima of f(x^2), where x=-8 and I'll go step by step.

Comment: @Testingman "I decided I will find minima of f(x^2), where x=-8" does not make sense as a problem. Whatever it means is certainly not the same as "find the minima of $x^2$," nor is it the same as "find the minima of $g(x) = f(x^2)$ for some particular function $f$." And if you've already decided that $x = -8$, I'm not sure what the goal is.

Comment: Dude, $-16$ is the slope of the tangent line to $f$ at $x=-8$. If you want to find the next point by this (that is: $f(-4+\Delta x)=f(-4)+\Delta x \cdot f'(-4)$) choosing $\Delta x$ is arbitrary but the less it is, the more accurate  the result will be.

Comment: If you choose $\Delta x = 0.1$ then: $f(-3.9)=f(-4)+0.1*f'(4)$, and for the next step: $f(-3.8)=f(-3.9)+0.1*f'(-3.9)$

Comment: This is called numerical solving. But you will never need to do so because the original method is far more easy and accurate.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar Now I get it. So if I would to go down the function, I need to arbitary select the number and -16 is just the slope. So eventually, slope will be zero or close to zero. Now I get it. Thank you good person

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Glad I could help. :)

Comment: @Testingman Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

For a differentiable function as $f(x)=x^2$, a necessary condition for a max/min point is that $f’(x)=2x=0\implies x=0$.

Note that it is not sufficient to determine what kind of point is x=0, we need to consider the sign of $f’(x)$ or to consider $f’’(x)$.

In this case

- for $x>0 \implies f’(x)>0$ that is $f$ increasing
- for $x<0 \implies f’(x)<0$ that is $f$ decreasing

thus $x=0$ is a minimum point.

Comment: Thank you. I understand this... But I am having problems to understand what -16 at x=-8 tells me.

Comment: Ah ok sorry but from the title I understood a different issue. Well anyway I’ve just answered also about that, indeed a negative derivative tell us that the function is decreasing in that point.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can construct a ***variation table***, for instance:

```
x |  ...  | x1 |  ...  | x2 |  ...
y'|  +/-  | 0  |  +/-  | 0  |  +/-
y |  +/-  | y1 |  +/-  | y2 |  +/-
```

If $y'=f'(x)=\text{negative }(-)$, this means that the rate of change is negative, and that $f(x)$ *at that point* is increasing.

Comment: thank you. But what does -16 tell me at this point?

Comment: @Testingman The rate it is decreasing. (e.g) If it says $-1$, it wouldn't be decreasing at a high rate..